# Convert float to Decimal preserving str() representation

Tags: python, subclass

I am trying to subclass `decimal.Decimal` so that floating point numbers get treated as strings, which in turn are treated as decimals.

Instead of:

```
>>> decimal.Decimal(1.1)
Decimal('1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625')
```

I convert the float to a str which in turn gets converted into Decimal:

```
>>> decimal.Decimal(str(1.1))
Decimal('1.1')
```

Since I find myself doing this a lot, I decided to subclass Decimal. But the following code throws an exception in Python 3.6.4:

```
import decimal

class D(decimal.Decimal):
    def __new__(self, value="0", context=None):
        value = str(value)
        super().__new__(value, context)

d = D(1.1)
print(d)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Better/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/scratch_4.py", line 8, in <module>
    d = D(1.1)
  File "C:/Users/Better/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/scratch_4.py", line 6, in __new__
    super().__new__(value, context)
TypeError: decimal.Decimal.__new__(X): X is not a type object (str)
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the wrong arguments to  `__new__` and you're not returning anything.

[Documentation on how to use `__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)

```
class D(decimal.Decimal):

    def __new__(cls, value="0", context=None):
        value = str(value)
        return super().__new__(cls, value, context)
```

That being said, you should probably be using `__init__` here, since you're not doing any class type manipulation that requires the use of `__new__`.

```
class D(decimal.Decimal):

    def __init__(self, value="0", context=None):
        value = str(value)
        super().__init__(self, value, context)
```

Comment: We cannot use `__init__` here, since the `Decimal` class does not use `__init__`. It is noted in the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/_pydecimal.py#L563) that `We're immutable, so use __new__ not __init__`. Also, `__init__` should not return anything.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
super().__new__(self, value, context)
```

`def __new__(self, value="0", context=None):` requires three positional arguments, `self`, `value` and `context`.

When you do `super().__new__(value, context)` `self` (from your function) becomes `value` and `context` becomes `value`, the last two values do not need to be defined to use the function so there is nothing alerting you to this,
`context` never actually gets passed to `super().__new__()`

Comment: I tried replacing the line with  `super().__new__(self, value, context)`. Result: No error, but outputs `None`

Comment: @ChaimG  Then `return super().__new__(value, context)` the value as suggested above